# Swift: How to assign a class's delegate to another class in current class?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

```
protocol TestDelegate {
    func toggleLeftPanel()
}
class A: UIViewController, TestDelegate {
    //...do sth.
    func toggleLeftPanel() {
        //do sth.
    }
    //...do sth.
}
class B: UIViewController {
    var delegate: TestDelegate?
    func onMenu() {
        delegate?.toggleLeftPanel()
    }
}
class C: UIViewController {
    func presentAction() {
        let b = b()
        b.delegate = A.self//Here will report an error

        let b = B()// I got the instance of B controller
        presentViewController(b, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Think that I am now in C UIViewController( this corresponding a screen in IPhone ), then I will go to the B UIViewController by click a button (presentAction). 
But when I arrived at B UIViewController, I found that onMenu not work( toggleLeftPanel not work ), because delegate property of b is nil, so I decide to assign a class( instance? ) to it( b.delegate ) before present b UIViewController, but I got an error "cannot assign a value of type 'xxxController.Type' to a value of type'xxxDelegate?'".
How could I resolve this problem? Or I should implement the `TestDelegate` in class C again and assign `b.delegate` to itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let b = b()
b.delegate = A.self
```

Codes above are completely nonsense. First, there is no class name "b". It should be let b = B(). Second, you should assign an instance to delegate. Not a class. Something like b.delegate = self. Please read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

You can also try codes below

```
protocol TestDelegate: class {
    func toggleLeftPanel()
}

class A: UIViewController, TestDelegate {
    //...do sth.
    func toggleLeftPanel() {
        //do sth.
    }
    //...do sth.
}

class B: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: TestDelegate?
    func onMenu() {
        delegate?.toggleLeftPanel()
    }
}

class C: UIViewController {
    func presentAction() {

        let a = A()
        let b = B()
        b.delegate = a
        presentViewController(b, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes, I made some typo. It should be `let b = B()`. I understand what you said, but what I think is: `class A` had already implement the delegate, could I use it agian? I want to assign an instance of `class A` to `b.delegate` in `func presenAction()` in `class C`, could this be done? (I don't want to let class C to follow the protocol, and then implement it, and then assign `self` to `b.delegate`)

Comment: I knew that make `class C` to conform `TestDelegate` and then implement it can reach the goal, but I just want to reuse `class A`, because it had already conformed `TestDelegate`, could this be done?

Comment: Ah, Now I see what you are trying to do. As long as you have a class A instance you can do it. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I think too much. As I build App by Storyboard, a xxxViewController corresponding a Storyboard, I unexpectedly  don't know how to create an instance of xxxViewController just because it corresponding a Storyboard(UI). Thank you very much! I'm a beginner.